# Getting results by latitude and longitude from SQLite

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have a database table with events. Each event has a location (latitude and longitude). I'm writing an API so I can display them on a map using Google Maps API. I only want to display records within the bounds where the map is currently pointing to. So, I get the bounds of the map and pass them on to the api.

```
var sql = `
  SELECT * 
  FROM event e 
  WHERE 1=1
`;
if(opts.status){
  sql += `AND e.status = '${opts.status}'`
}
if(opts.north){
  sql += `
          AND e.latitude IS NOT NULL
          AND e.latitude < ${opts.north}
        `
}
if(opts.south){
  sql += `
          AND e.latitude IS NOT NULL
          AND e.latitude > ${opts.south}
        `
}
if(opts.west){
  sql += `
          AND e.longitude IS NOT NULL
          AND e.longitude > ${opts.west}
        `
}
if(opts.east){
  sql += `
          AND e.longitude IS NOT NULL
          AND e.longitude < ${opts.east}
        `
}
```

This approach works very well, except when the map straddles the 180° line. Then I get 0 results. This is the resulting SQL in that situation:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM event e 
   WHERE 1=1

           AND e.status = 'approved'

           AND e.latitude IS NOT NULL
           AND e.latitude < 66.00592309328745

           AND e.latitude IS NOT NULL
           AND e.latitude > -16.496223071414896

           AND e.longitude IS NOT NULL
           AND e.longitude > 170.34568706699213

           AND e.longitude IS NOT NULL
           AND e.longitude < -46.216812933007816
```

My question is, how can I deal with this so it will give me accurate results?

Comment: Add conditions for values and switch `and` to `or` if needed (with correctly placed parenthesis)? BTW if you have both lower and upper bound for latitude/longitude then you have repeated `e.latitude/longitude IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around the logic of how those AND and OR statements should look like.

Comment: It's not that hard, now your condition is `e.longitude > 170.34568706699213 AND e.longitude < -46.216812933007816` can you find `x` that satisfies `170 < x < -46` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like:

```
AND ((e.longitude > ${opts.west}
     AND e.longitude < ${opts.east}
     AND  ${opts.east} > ${opts.west})
OR ((e.longitude > ${opts.west}
     OR e.longitude < ${opts.east})
     AND  ${opts.east} < ${opts.west}))
```

And maybe do the same for lattitude?